# Why am I getting NameError here

Tags: python

Could someone explain to me why am I getting `NameError: name 'b' is not defined` for [this](https://repl.it/repls/EnergeticUtilizedOctagon) code:

```
class Foo():
    a = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']
    b = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(a)}
    c = {b[t]: t for t in b}
```